# Creating a `State [Int] Int`

Tags: haskell, state-monad

Reading through [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#state), I'm trying to construct a `Stack [Int] Int`:

```
ghci>import Control.Monad.State

ghci> let stack = state ([1,2,3]) (1) :: State [Int] Int

<interactive>:58:20:
    Couldn't match expected type `s0 -> (State [Int] Int, s0)'
                with actual type `[t0]'
    In the first argument of `state', namely `([1, 2, 3])'
    In the expression: state ([1, 2, 3]) (1) :: State [Int] Int
    In an equation for `stack':
        stack = state ([1, 2, 3]) (1) :: State [Int] Int
```

How can I create a `Stack [Int] Int`?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this function? The way I understand the `State` monad, you need to be doing something to change the state.

Comment: `State [Int] Int` is really just a function of type `[Int] -> (Int, [Int])`. It doesn't "contain" a `[Int]` or a `Int`. You can create a *computation* which represents ignoring the previous state, setting the state to `[1,2,3]`, and returning 1 with `put [1,2,3] >> return 1` or `state (\_ -> (1, [1,2,3])`.

Comment: The tutorial goes through many steps. Did you notice the type synonym `type Stack = [Int]`? Once the state monad is introduced, it starts dealing with `State Stack a` (for various choices of `a`). So it’s not a `Stack [Int] Int` you want. (Or perhaps those were typos.)

Comment: Good straightforward answer from *user2407038*. There is no magic, just functions compound. Your example may be rewritten like `let sstack = state (\lst -> (sum lst, lst)) ; runState sstack [1,2,3,4]` results in `(10,[1,2,3,4])` . Your state is a list of numbers `:: [Int]` and monad is a function `sum` `:: [Int] -> Int` which returns state's sum `::Int`. In fact the parameter is a more generic `Num a` but used `Int` for briefness.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you're trying to do. `State s a` is essentially a `newtype` for a certain kind of function type (specifically `s -> (a, s)`), so it doesn't really make sense to make a `State` value from just a list. The simplified (internal) definition of `State` looks something like

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

Though you won't use the `State` constructor directly, it does illustrate the fact that a `State s a` value consists of a function.

You need a function that updates the state in some way (which could be considered a "`State` action"), then you can use `runState :: State s a -> s -> (a, s)` to execute the provided `State` action, given a certain initial state (the `s` argument).

It looks like you want to use `[1, 2, 3]` as your initial state, but you do also need to provide that update function (which is what you use to construct the `State s a` value itself).

In the Learn You a Haskell example, the `Stack` type synonym represents the actual stack data while `State Stack ...` represents a stateful action *on* the `Stack` data. For instance, an action of type `State Stack Int` uses a `Stack` value as its state and results in an `Int` when it is executed.